# Debugging web app in Android Studio missing tabs in DevTools?

Tags: flutter, devtools

When I run our web app from AS and start DevTools by tapping its icon in AS, it comes up but tabs like Network and Memory are missing? Below is a pic of what I'm seeing. Is there another way I should be starting DevTools when debugging our web app in AS?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some tools are missing for Web, there's a table here: https://dart.dev/tools/dart-devtools showing what's expected.

[image: Table of available Dart dev tools per platform]

There are some work-arounds/alternatives, for instance - https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/3710 suggests using the Chrome Network tool vs. the DevTools one.